# Swift immutable struct and convenient update

Tags: swift, struct

I have a struct

```
struct Offer {
    let offerId: Int
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let phoneNumber: String
    let address: String
    let createdAt: NSDate
    let price: Float
    let type: String
    let quantity: Int
    let instructions: [String]
    let votesCount: Int
    let featured: Bool
    let published: Bool
    let publishable: Bool
    let voted: Bool
    let user: PublicProfile
    let images: [OfferImage2]
    let imageIds: [String: Int]
    let featuredImage: String
    let countries: [String]

    var featuredAt: NSDate?
    var featuredTill: NSDate?
    var publishedAt: NSDate?
```

And I want to keep it immutable (use `let` instead of `var` when possible) but I have a problem. When I need to update a property I do following:

```
mutating func updateTitle(_title: String) {
        self = Offer(offerId: offerId, title: _title, description: description, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, address: address, createdAt: createdAt, price: price, type: type, quantity: quantity, instructions: instructions, votesCount: votesCount, featured: featured, published: published, publishable: publishable, voted: voted, user: user, images: images, imageIds: imageIds, featuredImage: featuredImage, countries: countries, featuredAt: featuredAt, featuredTill: featuredTill, publishedAt: publishedAt)
}
```

It works but I'm looking for more compact way to do this.

Comment: Why are you making things you want to mutate immutable? As a struct is a value type, annotating `title` as a `var` and mutating it normally will do the same as your current code, as the entire struct will be copied upon mutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tiny problem with your request:

> I want to keep it immutable

Don't go along with:

> When I need to update a property

If you meant by that that you don't want to allow to change this property from outside there is more elegant way.

You can make the setter `private`.

In **Offer.swift** (*you can set the title anywhere*):

```
struct Offer {
    let offerId: Int
    private(set) var title: String

    mutating func updateTitle(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

In **OtherClass.swift** (*you are not allowed to set the title*):

```
    var offer = Offer.init(offerId: 123, title: "Offer1")
    offer.title = "Offer2" //- Compilation error "Cannot assign to property: 'title' setter is inaccessible"
```

Comment: Thank you! It's what I'm looking for :)